# How to show other input fields of form only when checkbox is checked through php only

Tags: php

I want to only show these fields if checkbox is selected, if the checkbox is not selected then these fields should not appear. By using php programming language only.

```
<input type = "checkbox" id = "reg_cash" name = "reg_cash" value="yes">
<fieldset id = "submit">
<legend> <h2> Fiducials </h2> </legend>
<label for = "fiducials_panels"> Amount of panels with fiducials in % : </label> 
<input type = "number" step="any" id = "fiducials_panels" name = "fiducials_panels" required><br><br>
<label for = "Double-side"> Double-side fiducial recognition in % :</label> <input type = "number" step="any" id = "Double-side" name = "Double-side" required><br><br>
</fieldset><br>
```

Comment: PHP is server side programming language.you should use jquery for this

Comment: hey bro. php is server side and for this you need to send data and prossess it.if you want this we can help you

Comment: is it not possible to use only php rather than j query?

Comment: you have to submit a form after checking checkbox so upon post request you can do that using php but this is not suggested.

Comment: Actually in my form i have too many checkboxes and these checkboxes are conditional, each checkbox contain multiple input fields. if the checkbox is checked then the input fields of that checkbox should appear only similarly when the next chekbox is checked then the input fields of that checkbox appear only and so on. but i am using the submit button at then end of the form, how it is possible to use in place of checkbox. is there any solution or php code for this problem?

Comment: @hoseininjast could you please help out me, i am still waiting for your answer

Answer (score 0):

```js
$("#submit").hide();
$('input[type="checkbox"]'). click(function(){
  if(document.getElementById("reg_cash").checked){
    $("#submit").show();
  }else{
    $("#submit").hide();
    }
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type = "checkbox" id = "reg_cash" name = "reg_cash" value="yes">

<fieldset id = "submit">
<legend> <h2> Fiducials </h2> </legend>
<label for = "fiducials_panels"> Amount of panels with fiducials in % : </label> 
<input type = "number" step="any" id = "fiducials_panels" name = "fiducials_panels" required><br><br>
<label for = "Double-side"> Double-side fiducial recognition in % :</label> <input type = "number" step="any" id = "Double-side" name = "Double-side" required><br><br>
</fieldset><br>
```

Comment: thanks for sending cod, i just want to know did you use jquery?

Comment: Absolutely Yes. Check First line of code `<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>`.

Comment: i checked that already. actually my requirement is to use only php and don't show anykind of code on websource. is it possible with jquery?

Answer (score 0):

try this code bro

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="reg_cash" name="reg_cash" value="yes">
<fieldset id="submit">
    <legend><h2> Fiducials </h2></legend>
    <div id="first">
        <label for="fiducials_panels"> Amount of panels with fiducials in % : </label>
        <input type="number" step="any" id="fiducials_panels" name="fiducials_panels" required
               onkeypress="showsecond()"><br><br>
    </div>
    <div id="second" style="display: none">
        <label for="Double-side"> Double-side fiducial recognition in % :</label>
        <input type="number" step="any" id="Double-side" name="Double-side" required><br><br>
    </div>
</fieldset><br>
<script>
    function showsecond() {
        var x = document.getElementById("second");
            if (x.style.display === "none") {
                x.style.display = "block";
            }
    }
</script>
```